# Delete empty columns in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I created a macro to remove empty columns from a worksheet.

How do you apply it to all worksheets?

Here's the code for removing columns:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
Dim Col As Integer

 With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  For Col = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
   If IsEmpty(Cells(1048562, Col)) And IsEmpty(Cells(1, Col)) Then
    If Cells(1048562, Col).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then Columns(Col).Delete
   End If
  Next Col
 End With

End Sub
```

And this is the one I've used to remove empty rows from all worksheets.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

    Dim row As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For row = 10 To 1 Step -1
            If IsError(ws.Cells(row, 4)) Then
                ws.Rows(row).Delete
            ElseIf ws.Cells(row, 4).Value = "" Then
                ws.Rows(row).Delete
            End If
        Next row
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A merge of those codes would look like this:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyColumns()

    Dim row As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Col As Integer

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Col = ws.UsedRange.Column + ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(1048562, Col)) And IsEmpty(ws.Cells(1, Col)) Then
            If ws.Cells(1048562, Col).End(xlUp).row = 1 Then ws.Columns(Col).Delete
            End If
        Next Col
    Next ws

End Sub
```